# How to filter varchar in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I filter a row with a varchar field in SQL? If I filter a integer, like:

```
insured_id=5
```

It works fine. But if I filter for a string:

```
name like "Bob Bird"
```

It gives me `ERROR: column "Bob Bird" doesn't exist`

I am sure its a stupid thing, but couldn't find what to do

Comment: You need single quotes around string constants, not double quotes.  I vote to lose this type of error as a simple typographical error.

Comment: See the manual for the correct syntax: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Comment: So it was a stupid thing indeed. Thanks!

Comment: If you are familiar with SQL Server or MS Access, the double quotes are akin to [Bob Bird], meaning it thinks "Bob Bird" is a field in a table.  They are also used for aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be,

```
name like '%Bob Bird%'
```

or if you want case insensitive then use,

```
name ilike '%Bob Bird%'
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL is something in most popular databases. It's built in; whether you're in mysql, oracle or sybase you need to use single ticks. If you use double quotation you will need to escape it with \"

Comment: No, double quotes `"` do **not** need to be "escaped" in SQL